# Finding a matching value on two columns

Tags: sql

I need to find matching values in two columns in same table, but with different rows.

```
|  id |  b  |  c  |
======================
|  1 |  2  |  3  |
======================
|  2 |  2  |  4  |
======================
| 3 |  2  |  5  |
======================
|  4 |  2  |  1  |
======================
|  5 |  3  |  1  |
======================
|  6 |  6  |  1  |
======================
|  7 |  7  |  1  |
======================
| 8 |  8  |  1  |
======================
```

what I want is the value 3 is in for both columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this self join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.b
FROM your_table t
INNER JOIN your_table s
ON t.b = s.c
AND t.id <> s.id
```

Comment: this works, how do i get the same result when i query the columns b AND c (WHERE b = 2 AND c = 1) and it still gives me the result of 3

Comment: great, you mean you want to find the rows where b=2 and c=1? please elaborate.